# How to switch between windows in the Mail app

Tags: macos

When I'm writing a new email, I would like to know the shortcut to go back to the In mailbox and vice versa.

In Chrome, I use the <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> command, and it works perfectly.

In Xcode, this shortcut works but only if the project has only one tab.

(I'm using an AZERTY keyboard)

Answer (score 0):

Ok I finally found a solution, it's to use <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd> and do some modifications in some apps.

Explaination : with AZERTY keyboards, the default system shortcut to go to the next window is actually <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd> .

In the Mail app, <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd> is to show all the windows. You can see the shortcut in `Presentation > Display all tabs` (it's in French in my setup I'm so not sure about the translation here). So I was actually using the wrong shortcut from the start.

In Xcode though, <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd> is the default shortcut to create breakpoints, so I had to remove this shortcut though.